# Brake vs Coast in BLDC

Tags: power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm using Brushless DC Motor. what is the difference between Coast and rake in Brushless DC motors ? application of each ? and if there is consideration of motor speed when choosing one of them?

If I use braking at high speed, does that affect motor and circuit temperature?.

Comment: Do you know the definition of brake and coast? They are just regular words and they are what they mean.

Comment: @DKNguyen i'm embedded software engineer and use Motor driver that use those definitions .from experiment i found that coast take long time to stop motor than brake.i want to know which one choose according to the answer.

Comment: There are thousands of applications so nobody's going to answer that because it's too broad - so what's your specific application?

Comment: @Andyaka application is changing motor speed according to specific output .

Comment: @Andyaka using high speed requires which of these coast or brake ? if there is in tutorial for that please mention it

Comment: Coast is simpler, but if you need the motor to stop fast you need to brake. You know your requirements, we don't, so the rest is up to you.

Comment: @BrianDrummond  using brake affect motor in high speed ?

Comment: Brakes wouldn't be much use if they didn't work at high speed. Maybe I don't understand what you'er asking.

Comment: @BrianDrummond i mean if i used brake in high speed, is that affect motor and circuit temperature ?

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental difference between coasting and braking is the same for an electric motor as for any other means of producing motion. For coasting, the source of power is turned off or otherwise removed and the driven equipment stops because there is nothing driving it. For braking, some force, a braking force, is applied to counteract the tendency of a moving mass to continue moving.

With an electric motor, the motor itself can produce a braking force. The various types of motors varying levels of tendency to produce braking torque. The braking torque that various types of motors can produce can be enhanced and controlled in various ways.

When a motor provides braking torque, it acts as a generator. It takes the mechanical energy from the rotating mass of the load and converts it to electrical energy. A limited amount of braking energy can be converted to heat in the motor. With proper control, a motor can produce braking torque that is comparable to driving torque. To dissipate energy at a rate comparable to the motor's power rating, an appropriately sized resistor or bank of resistors can be provided. Another alternative is to provide a system for returning the braking energy to the power source.

The various types of motors and electronic speed controllers each have their own requirements for implementing controlled braking. Fundamentally, they all facilitate the operation of the motor as a generator. The motor is decelerated by the control system and the generated energy is directed to braking resistors or back to the source.

Whether to just allow the motor to coast to a stop or to apply braking and the amount of braking is determined by the needs of the application. The application is the driven machine and the process or function performed by the driven machine. The details of the process may include related processes that may be affected and any manual activity performed by operating personnel. Some types of driven machinery naturally stops quickly when the driving force is removed. Other types of equipment may take a long time to stop. In some situations it is important to stop the machinery quickly. In other situations, it doesn't matter how long it coasts.

Safety may be a factor in determining whether breaking is needed. However, using the motor as a brake may not be the safest alternative. Sometimes it is preferable for the motor to have a spring-set brake that will stop the operation very quickly when power is removed whether intentionally or by power failure.

Motor speed is not directly relevant. The mechanical energy stored in a moving mass is proportional to the speed of motion. The stored mechanical energy relative to the energy dissipated in the process is always an important factor in designing a braking system.

Answer (score 3):

```
"If I use braking at high speed, does that affect motor and circuit temperature?".
```

That depends how you design your braking. It certainly can. You need to put the energy somewhere and there are at least three approaches :

1. Shorting the motor (brakes hard, heats the motor),
2. Resistive braking (higher value resistor brakes less hard. Dumps heat into the resistor)
3. Regenerative braking. Must be designed into the controller, so that it can be used as a boost converter to recharge the battery.